# Data structure: a graph that's similar to a tree - but not a tree

Tags: data-structures, graph

I have implemented a data structure in C, based upon a series of linked lists, that appears to be similar to a tree - but not enough to be referred as such, because in theory it allows the existence of cycles. Here's a basic outline of the nodes:

- There is a single, identifiable root that doesn't have a parent node or brothers;
- Each node contains a pointer to its "father", its nearest "brother" and the first of his "children";
- There are "outer" nodes without children and brothers.

How can I name such a data structure? It cannot be a tree, because even if the pointers are clearly labelled and used differently, cycles like father->child->brother->father may very well exist. My question is: terms such as "father", "children" and "brother" can be used in the context of a graph or they are only reserved for trees? After quite a bit of research I'm still unable to clarify this matter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can still call it a tree, because the foundation is a tree data structure.  There is precedence for my claim: "Patricia Tries" are referred to as trees even though their leaf nodes may point up the tree (creating cycles).  I'm sure there are other examples as well.

It sounds like the additional links you have are essentially just for convenience, and could be determined implicitly (rather than stored explicitly).  By storing them explicitly you impose additional invariants on your tree operations (insert, delete, etc), but do not affect the underlying organization, which is a tree.

Precisely because you are naming and treating those additional links separately, they can be thought of as an "overlay" on top of your tree.

In the end it doesn't really matter what you call it or what category it falls into if it works for you.  Reading a book like Sedgewick's "Algorithms in C" you realize that there are tons of data structures out there, and nothing wrong with inventing your own!

One more point: Trees are a special case of graphs, so there is nothing wrong with referring to it as a graph (or using graph algorithms on it) as well.